# Time conflicts and empty messages - Realtime chat application

Tags: javascript, python, django, chat, real-time

community.

Problem: I'm working on a real-time django chat application. When user messages it shows the right current time but, it's gets changed to a different time on refershing the page.

Here are the snaps for your reference:
[Real time chatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQoLe.png)
[After refreshing the page - Note-time has been changed on refreshing and some empty messages are coming as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxmq0.png)

What i want is .... as a real-time chat application the time and empty message should not show on refreshing the page.

Here is the code that i've implemented:

```
message model

class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added',)
```

```
Java Script

<script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-roomname').textContent);
    const userName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-username').textContent);
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
        + roomName
        + '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log('onclose')
    }

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

        if (data.message) {
            const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
            const messageHTML = `
                <div class="message ${data.username === userName ? 'self' : 'other'}">
                    <div class="message-content">
                        <b>${data.username}</b>: ${data.message}
                    </div>
                    <div class="message-time">
                        ${currentTime}
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
            document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML += messageHTML;
        } else {
            {% comment %} alert('The message was empty!') {% endcomment %}
        }

        scrollToBottom();
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        const message = messageInputDom.value;

        console.log({
            'message': message,
            'username': userName,
            'room': roomName
        })

        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': userName,
            'room': roomName
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';

        return false
    };

    /**
    * A function for finding the messages element, and scroll to the bottom of it.
    */
    function scrollToBottom() {
        let objDiv = document.getElementById("chat-messages");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }

    // Add this below the function to trigger the scroll on load.
    scrollToBottom();
</script>
```